# How to redirect user to specific page after open the notification phonegap

Tags: php, android, cordova, push-notification

I'm trying to redirect user to a page after open the notification. I'm using this plugin to send notification https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push and php. 
I don't find how to integrate my URL.

Thanks to help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "new_page";
```

Comment: Where I write this line in push.on

Comment: push.on('notification', function(data) {
window.location.href = "new_page";
});